# How to select vector with the greatest nth element

Tags: matlab, vector, find, max, vectorization

In MATLAB, given to vectors `A` and `B`, I want to find a vectorized solution to select the entire vector with the greatest nth element (i.e. 4th).

```
A = [1, 4, 8, 10];
B = [2, 15, 2, 11];
```

Using `max` I can find the greatest 4th element between both vectors, but I would like to take it entirely.

```
C = max(A(4), B(4));
```

Comment: what should happen if A(4) == B(4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second return value of [`max`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#outputarg_I), i.e. the index, as follows:

```
X = [A; B];
[~, index] = max(X(:, 4));
C = X(index, :);
```

**For people loving *single line solutions***

```
C = A * (A(4) > B(4)) + B * (B(4) > A(4));
```

or just define it as a function

```
function getVectorWithLargestNthElement (A, B, N)
    X = [A; B];
    [~, index] = max(X(:, N));
    C = X(index, :);
end
```

and you will be able to use it as a single line:

```
C = getVectorWithLargestNthElement (A, B, 4)
```

Comment: any possibility of having that solution vectorized in a single line?

Comment: @AJMA single line coding is by no means _vectorization_, it's just compact writing. It's better to write your code in the clearer way, not the most compact way.